# Does an open session in hibernate necessarily imply that I have a connection to the database?

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, mariadb

For testing purposes, I changed my context.xml to

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    maxActive="1" maxIdle="0" maxWait="10000"
    name="jdbc/ourDB" removeAbandoned="true"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="300" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"
    username="root"
    password="something"
    validationQuery="select 1;" />
```

However according to the debugger in Eclipse, two threads have an open session at the same time.

This is according to

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
if (!session.isOpen()) {
        session = session.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        log.warn("initSessionIfClosed] Session was closed so it was reopened");
}
```

Is this actually possible or am I debugging something in the wrong way (I cleaned the project in Eclipse and the context seems to be deployed locally).

I can provide more specifics if necessary.

Thank you very much.

Update:

According to .hashCode, the two session objects are different and 
    mysqladmin -i 1 processlist

shows two processes.

+-----+----------+-----------+-----------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+----------+
| Id  | User     | Host      | db              | Command | Time | State | Info             | Progress |
+-----+----------+-----------+-----------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+----------+

| 79  | root     | localhost |                 | Sleep   | 3501 |       |                  | 0.000    |

| 133 | barthlen | localhost |                 | Query   | 0    | init  | show processlist | 0.000    |

| 174 | root     | localhost | db | Sleep   | 367  |       |                  | 0.000    |

| 175 | root     | localhost | db | Sleep   | 416  |       |                  | 0.000    |

+-----+----------+-----------+-----------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+----------+

So, could it be that this a bug from tomcat?

Comment: Only 3 connections idle?  Not a problem.

Comment: Don't connect your application as `root`, `GRANT` a new user for your application and use that.  For security, `GRANT` only `ON dbname.*`

Comment: The problem was that I expected just one connection in total. But changing maxActive to maxTotal changed the behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Each hibernate session equate a JDBC Connection, a JDBC Connection shouldn't be accessed by two threads actually, because each thread should be bound to a one and only one database transaction, as the hibernate session is not thread safe, you need to set a proper transaction isolation level here.

Comment: Just so that I understand it correctly, you are suggesting setting defaultTransactionIsolation to something other than REPEATABLE_READ which seems to be the default for mysql?

Comment: @MarkusBarthlen Actually it depdents. there are four transaction level defined in the `java.sql.Connection`, you need select a proper one.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the reason seems to be that I have to use maxTotal instead of maxActive since I am using a Tomcat that is newer than Tomcat 7.